# Compiling C code in terminal, always shows a % if I don't put a newline

Tags: c, macos, terminal

So when I run a program in terminal, for instance just a simple printf,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   printf("Hello");
   return 0;
}
```

In terminal, it will print
Hello%
But if I run it as `printf("Hello\n");` , then there is no `%` not even in the blank line under it.

Does anyone know what is going on?

**Edit:**

To compile, in terminal: `gcc hello.c`

To run: `./a.out`

What terminal is returning: `Hello%`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please, provide us more details. Show us the entire code and how you run the program.

Comment: I edited to show how I am compiling/running it. I don't really know what other information I can provide.

Comment: So you don't have a `#include <stdio.h>` in your code?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I do have that in my code yes, my apologies.

Comment: Are you using % as Bash indicator?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it's printing an extra garbage character at the end of your string. For whatever reason your string literal's length is being calculated incorrectly.

Adding a null byte at the end of your string, like this...

```
"hello\0"
```

... should fix the issue. It's a good habit to null-terminate all char-array strings.